# pandas dataframe check if column contains string that exists in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to learn about Dataframes but I'm still a beginner.
Let's say I have a DataFrame that contains two columns:

```
Name       Description
Am         Owner of Am
BQ         Employee at BQ  
JW         Employee somewhere
```

I want to check if the name is also a part of the description, and if so keep the row. If it's not, delete the row. In this case, it will delete the 3rd row (JW   Employee somewhere)

Comment: Look at the timing with the answers. You can test it yourself. speed is important

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] in x['Description'], axis = 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
s='|'.join(df.Name)#Join the search words into a pattern
df=df[df.Description.str.contains(s)]#Mask using boolean select
print (df)

 Name     Description
0   Am     Owner of Am
1   BQ  Employee at BQ


%%timeit
s='|'.join(df.Name)
df[df.Description.str.contains(s)]
537 µs ± 2.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] in x['Description'], axis = 1)]
1.27 ms ± 3.22 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: This answer is faster and will serve you better in a large dataset

Comment: Good, but not 'None' - protected)