# pandas dataframe-python check if string exists in another column ignoring upper/lower case

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the same dataframe as i asked in ([pandas dataframe check if column contains string that exists in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62603123/13666184))

```
Name       Description
Am         Owner of Am
BQ         Employee at bq  
JW         Employee somewhere
```

I want to check if the name is also a part of the description, and if so keep the row. If it's not, delete the row. In this case, it will delete the 3rd row (JW Employee somewhere)

I am using

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] in x['Description'], axis = 1)]
```

In this case, it is also deleting the row of BQ because in the description "bq" is in lowercase. In there anyway to use to same syntax but with taking into consideration case sensitivity ?

Answer (score 4):

Use `.lower()` to make it case-agnostic:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].lower() in x['Description'].lower(), axis=1)]
```

Note that this will consider `"am"` as a match on `"amy"`. You may wish to use word boundaries to prevent this:

```
>>> def filter(x): 
...     return bool(re.search(rf"(?i)\b{x['Name']}\b", x["Description"]))
...
>>> df[df.apply(filter, axis=1)]
  Name     Description
0   Am     Owner of Am
1   BQ  Employee at bq
```

Or `split` which handles regex special characters better:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x["Name"].lower() in x["Description"].lower().split(), axis=1)]
```

Comment: The problem with the first solution will be that `Am` is in `Owner of Am`  and  in `Owner of Amy` too, and in the second case it will not give the desired output, IIUC.

Comment: OP hasn't really specified that there's a problem with substrings--that's just a guess/suggestion on my part. The second will only fail if there are regex special characters in the string. You can use `split` which is probably better. How else would it fail, though, out of curiosity?

Comment: That's true, you're right, the OP doesn't specified the problem. But if that's the case, I mean, if it's about the substings, the first one will not work. And no, the second is awesome and it will not fail in the guessed substring problem :)!

Answer (score 3):

You should use

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] in x['Description'].split(' '), axis = 1)]
```

Comment: Yess .lower() should also be added along with .split() . Here it is     df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].lower() in x['Description'].lower().split(' '), axis = 1)] . Thanks @ggorlen

Comment: ``split`` by default splits by spaces, ``.split()`` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `lower`, `split` and `isin`:

```
msk=df.Description.str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(df.Name.str.lower()).any(1)
df[msk]
```

Output:

```
  Name     Description
0   Am     Owner of Am
1   BQ  Employee at bq
```

---

**Details**
First we use `str.lower` to cast the strings to lower case

```
print(df.Description.str.lower())
0           owner of am
1        employee at bq
2    employee somewhere
Name: Description, dtype: object
```

Then we split the strings and expand the lists:

```
print(df.Description.str.lower().str.split(expand=True))
          0          1     2
0     owner         of    am
1  employee         at    bq
2  employee  somewhere  None
```

Then we check the values that are the `df.name` with `isin`

```
print(df.Description.str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(df.Name.str.lower()))
   0      1      2
0  False  False   True
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
```

And finally make `any` in axis 1 (row-wise), to see if at least one word matched:

```
print(df.Description.str.lower().str.split(expand=True).isin(df.Name.str.lower()).any(1))
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen, yes, just edited the answer, you can compare the column without `tolist`.