# Update for Dataframe python check if string in column is in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I asked this question on [pandas dataframe-python check if string exists in another column ignoring upper/lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63370246/13666184) but i have a new update

I have a new row in a new dataframe :

```
Id    CompanyName                                           EDescription

4    finance company - finance service sol         Project manager at finance company
5    finance company - finance service sol         IT
```

i want my output to return rows that contain any string from CompanyName that is in EDescription. Even if it's not exactly the same.
if i use `df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'] in x['Description'], axis = 1)]` with all upper/lower case condition, i still get an empty dataframe.

i want my final output to be :

```
Id    CompanyName                                           EDescription
    
4    finance company - finance service sol         Project manager at finance company
```

Comment: Please, could you be more specific? What do you mean by any string? You meant by all strings in CompanyName: `[finance, company, finance, service, sol ]`... or you meant by all the substrings separated by `' - '`: `[finance company , finance service sol]`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
mask = (
    df.apply(lambda x :
             x['CompanyName'].split("-")[0].strip().lower() in x['EDescription'].lower(), axis=1)
)

df[mask]
```

---

```
   Id  ...                        EDescription
0   4  ...  Project manager at finance company
```